# Android 7.0 call block feature

Tags: 7.0-nougat, call-screening, huawei-honor-7

I have honor 8 lite with android 7.0
I block a number from default dialer app, It should be blocked now but instead when someone calls me from that number he hears 1 or 2 seconds of my phone ringing, then the call hangs. So that the other party can easily understand that his/her call has been blocked.
I want that the call must be blocked silently, without the calling party knowing anything about it. 
The caller must get message such as -- Not reachable or phone is switched off.
I know that this feature may be network dependent but my old feature phone was doing it very smartly but my smart phone fails to do so.
Any suggestions on how to block calls with android 7.0 stealthily.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do something very similar on my device running Marshmallow to prevent tele callers and quite successfully so :)

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn.

### Since I don't have Nougat can't test, but should run fine

In the first macro, it is configured here for non contacts. You can select individually the numbers in your case

[image]
[image]

The SMS portion of first macro is expanded below - you can configure it to your liking

[image]

**Note:** Two macros are strictly not required. You can add action of second macro in first itself - I needed two macros for customisation which is not shown here